# Continue running the code if user input is valid

Tags: python

I'm writing some code in Python that calculates the area of a triangle or a circle, depending on the user's choice. I want to write "if the user's choice is a C (for circle), continue running", but everything I write doesn't work and it shows an error.

I have:

```
option = raw_input('Enter C for Circle and T for Triangle: ')
circle = 'C'
tringle = 'T'
if option == circle:
    return option
```

Comment: What error? And is this code inside a function?

Comment: Can you try to create a [mcve]?

Comment: This is really all I have

Comment: @curious Post the full code.

Comment: Well, the error message is clear: you can't use `return` outside of a function.

Comment: The code I posted is really all I have

Comment: How do I turn it into a function then?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you cannot return a value unless it is from a function.

If you want to accomplish a running example you can easily use a `while` loop like so:

```
circle = 'C'
tringle = 'T'
value = True
while value:
    option = raw_input('Enter C for Circle and T for Triangle: ')
    # check lower() so capitalization doesn't matter
    if option.lower() == circle:
        # do something
        print("Do something, 'C' has been selected") 
        pass
    else:
        value = False
```

As an explanation, if you are unclear on what is happening above. The while loop is always True if the selected option is `circle`, thus the loop never terminates and the iteration continues. If the selected option is not `circle`, the value of `value` will not be True, so the loop breaks before the code in the loop is executed again.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `SyntaxError` because you are calling `return` despite not having any function defined. According to Python syntax, you can only return from inside of a function. I'd recommend reading up on how to create Python functions (this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-in-python/) does a good job of explaining it)

Comment: How do I turn it into a function, then?

Comment: It sounds like you need a tutorial. StackOverflow isn't a good site for that.

Comment: @curious, I'd recommend checking out the link I added to my answer, it's a good introduction to python functions